# Event receiver not firing when item added by workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, event-receivers

event receiver not firing when item is added by workflow. Its working perfectly when we manually add item to list. I am using SP Designer 2013. When we add item through workflow, it shows that item is created on behalf of admin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is your problem.  SharePoint workflows will not run under the admin user account.

Comment: no  i am not login with admin